# Bootstrap Modal backdrop css

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to use the backdrop effect of the bootstrap modal, but without loading a modal. But am not able to do it properly. So, What css does the Bootstrap backdrop use internally ??

Comment: May be inspecting the HTML can help..

Comment: I tried to do that but couldn't find any. TechMa9iac

Answer (score 2):

Your backdrop must have a HIGHER z-index than the content you want to cover, AND a LOWER z-index than the box you want to operate(dropdown/popup/modal).

You may want to add a backdrop in the **show/shown** event:

```
$('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>')
.insertBefore('.yourPopupBox')
.click(function () {
    //hide the popup box here
    //$(".yourPopupBox").hide();
});
```

And you must remove the backdrop in the **hidden** event:

```
var backdrop = $(".yourPopupBox").parent().find('.dropdown-backdrop');
if (backdrop) {
    backdrop.remove();
}
```

And the CSS can be like:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  //background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 990;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

```
<div id="backdrop" style="position: fixed;width: 100%;height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);"></div>
```

Comment: But this is just acting as a background. It's not giving the overlay effect on other elements within the div.

Comment: add a z-index of 10000 and check

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this as well:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px) contrast(.1);
}
```